# A SELECT Query Joining Data From The Same Table

Tags: sql, join, select, union

The barcode values in the table below exist multiple times for certain transaction types. I'm filtering the data through a SELECT query using one specific transaction type (e.g. 'Input'), but would also like the data from another transaction type that matches with the specific barcodes being pulled through.

Data:

```
| Weight | Barcode | Transaction_Type | Order_No |
|:------:|:-------:|:----------------:|:--------:|
| 27.81  | 1111222 | PO               | 101      |
| 27.81  | 1111222 | Input            | 0        |
| 22.64  | 1111333 | PO               | 102      |
| 22.64  | 1111333 | Input            | 0        |
```

Desired Output:

```
| Weight | Barcode | Transaction_Type | Order_No |
|:------:|:-------:|:----------------:|:--------:|
| 27.81  | 1111222 | Input            | 101      |
| 22.64  | 1111333 | Input            | 102      |
```

Comment: based on what it display order number 101 and 102?

Comment: Please post your current query.  Also, tag your question with your DBMS because sql syntax varies by vendor and version.

Comment: Desired output does not match the description of what you want to get. If you want to get all records with barcodes that exist in ( Transaction_Type='Input' ) filter then your desired output is the same as Data. Or I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, make things a bit difficult (if possible.) Will it always be 2 rows per barcode, or can it be 1 or 3?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT C.WEIGHT,C.BARCODE,C.TRANSACTION_TYPE,C2.ORDERE_NO
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS C
JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS C2 ON C.BARCODE=C2.BARCODE
WHERE C.TRANSACTION_TYPE='INPUT' AND C2.TRANSACTION_TYPE='PO'
```